# Calling Private Methods Recursively

Tags: function, oop, recursion, private, self

I am writing a code that has a class Fraction with attributes Numerator and Denominator. The Output should display the fraction in a simplified form. For e.g. 20/100 should be display as 1/5.
I have tried the below code but getting a Type Error as below:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'NoneType'

class fraction:
    def get_data(self):
        self.__num=int(input("Enter the Nr:"))
        self.__deno=int(input("Enter the Dr:"))
        if (self.__deno==0):
            print("Fraction not possible")
            exit()
    def display_data(self):
        self.__simplify()
        print(self.__num,"/",self.__deno)
    def __simplify(self):
        print("The simplified fraction is")
        common_divisor=self.__GCD(self.__num,self.__deno)
        self.__num=(self.__num)/(common_divisor)
        self.__deno=(self.__deno)/(common_divisor)
    def __GCD(self,a,b):
        if (b==0):
            return a
        else:
            self.__GCD(b,a%b)
f=fraction()
f.get_data()
f.display_data()
```

I have no clue how to solve this Error. Please help me as i am new to Python and want to build strong basics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this function definition:

```
def __GCD(self,a,b):
    if (b==0):
        return a
    else:
        self.__GCD(b,a%b)
```

There's no `return` statement on the `else` clause.  (Also, the `else` clause can be *implicit* instead of *explicit*.)  Instead try:

```
def __GCD(self, a, b):
    if b == 0:
        return a
    
    return self.__GCD(b, a % b)
```